# firefox 8 on Mac OSX Lion - browser redirections don't seem to work

Tags: firefox, osx-lion, redirection

For example, when you login to paypal and you get a page saying "if you see this for longer than 5 seconds, click here" or something to that effect - the redirect that *should* have happened there consistently fails on my browser.

301's are fine but anything like a meta:refresh tag just doesn't work.

The browser is kitted out with firebug, web developer toolbar, and a few others - and I've changed the ABE settings before but can't remember where to find them now.

Point is, does anyone know what setting I've broken that would allow these redirects normally? It's starting to hinder my testing somewhat :)

Answer (score 0):

After trawling through `about:config`, I figured out that it was the web developer toolbar, I must have changed this setting in it at some point:

```
webdeveloper.meta.redirects.disable **true**
```

I set this to false and working now :)